# Calling methods C#.NET from JAVA

Tags: java, c#, dll

I have a dll created out of a C#.NET project and I would like to call the methods from a java program. I was wondering as to what sort of opportunities exist to accomplish this and then I came across JNA and JNI. Which one should I use for my purpose? Any suggestions? All I need is to call the methods in a class written using C#.NET and process the results from my Java program.

Comment: Does this help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13093/C-method-calls-within-a-Java-program ?

Comment: But why i will need JNI, have you some explication ?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on your application, But you could place the C# DLL within a service e.g. WCF and expose the functionality to the Java code that way. Using wsimport to generate your client code within Java.

It saves the need to use cross over tools like JNI...